# How to find text inside table with div parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find text inside div parent with table, if i write any text inside my search bar i want to show only the result and the rest of the divs hidde, i have differents td that i want search in the four cells (left to rigth) the last cell is not important

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="caja-orden-curso" alt="3">
    <div class="contenido-curso">
        <table id="perrito" border="1" style="width:98%">
           <tr>
              <td width="220" height="100">
                 <div id="vehicle_type" class="top-order">
                    36624
                 </div>
              </td>
              <td width="200">
                 <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
                    <span id="created">02/02/2016 10:59</span>
                 </div>
              </td>
              <td width="300">
                 <div class="order-details-top" style="height: 14px;">presidente masaryk, 29, , polanco</div>
                 <div class="order-details-bottom" style="height: 23px;">colima, 323, , roma norte</div>
              </td>
              <td width="120">
                 <div class="order-details-top">
                    alexis
                    <div>
                       <div class="order-details-bottom">
                          saul
                       </div>
              </td>
              <td width="120">
              565897423
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="color-lateral-curso">
    </div>
    <div class="tam-tabla-orden">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="caja-orden-curso" id="statu-20" alt="12">
    <div class="contenido-curso">
        <table id="perrito" border="1" style="width:98%">
           <tr>
              <td width="220" height="100">
                 <div id="vehicle_type" class="top-order">
                    35684
                 </div>
              </td>
              <td width="200">
                 <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
                    <span id="created">01/02/2016 10:59</span>
                 </div>
              </td>
              <td width="300">
                 <div class="order-details-top" style="height: 14px;">yumnbvfd, 78984,</div>
                 <div class="order-details-bottom" style="height: 23px;">jhgfre, 483</div>
              </td>
              <td width="120">
                 <div class="order-details-top">
                    rtynbv
                    <div>
                       <div class="order-details-bottom">
                          zsdf
                       </div>
              </td>
              <td width="120">
              565897423
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="color-lateral-finalizada-segundo" id="statu-9">
    </div>
    <div class="tam-tabla-orden">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my Script:

```
$("#buscador").keyup(function() {
  var dInput = $(this).val();
      if (!this.value) {
         $('div.caja-orden-curso').fadeIn();
      }
      else
        {
         $("table#perrito").each(function()
            {
             $(this).find('div.top-order:contains(' + dInput + ')').length > 0 ?
               $(this).show() : $(this).parents('div.caja-orden-curso').fadeOut(); 
          });
       }

  });
```

My example only work with the first cell with the other three cells i cant.

This is my [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vbmzyypd/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs in a page must be unique. So change `id="perrito"` to `class="perrito"` and do the following.

```
$("table.perrito").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('div:contains(' + dInput + ')').length) 
    $(this).parents('div.caja-orden-curso').fadeIn();
  else
    $(this).parents('div.caja-orden-curso').fadeOut();
});
```

**[DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vbmzyypd/10/)**

Comment: typo I guess. table.perrito] should be table.perrito

Comment: Not a problem. It was easily spotted :-)

Comment: thanks, with this code i can find with the first cell but i want to find with the other three cells for example date, name,address even name, so i can use something like this `if ( ($(this).find('div.top-order:contains(' + dInput + ')').length) && ($(this).find('div.order-steps:contains(' + dInput + ')').length))` ?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Only one and last thing, if i found a result its ok is showing  but if i erase text when i return to empty input sometimes show all but any others not, can you explain me, sorry for ask every step but i want to learn about it

Comment: @victor It can be fixed by removing the `$(this).hide()`/`$(this).show()`, those are not needed. :)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Thanks man, you saved my day, p.d. i trying follow you in twitter but i cant find you with your user is showing here in your profile

Answer (score 3):

Here you used find funtion on "top-order" class only.if you want work with all 4 cells then you apply this class on all of three cells also. You may try this

```
<div class="caja-orden-curso" alt="3">
<div class="contenido-curso">
  <table id="perrito" border="1"style="width:98%">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="220" height="100">
                         <div id="vehicle_type" class="top-order">
                          36624
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="200">
                          <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps top-order">
                            <span id="created">02/02/2016 10:59</span>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="300">
                        <div class="order-details-top top-order" style="height: 14px;">presidente masaryk, 29, , polanco</div>
<div class="order-details-bottom top-order" style="height: 23px;">colima, 323, , roma norte</div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="120">
                          <div class="order-details-top top-order">
                          alexis
                          <div>
                            <div class="order-details-bottom top-order">
                          saul
                          </div>
                        </td>
                         <td width="120">
                          565897423
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                <div class="color-lateral-curso">
                </div>
                <div class="tam-tabla-orden">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="caja-orden-curso" id="statu-20" alt="12">
                <div class="contenido-curso">
                    <table id="perrito" border="1"style="width:98%">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="220" height="100">
                         <div id="vehicle_type" class="top-order">
                          35684
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="200">
                          <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps top-order">
                            <span id="created">01/02/2016 10:59</span>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="300">
                        <div class="order-details-top" style="height: 14px;">yumnbvfd, 78984,</div>
<div class="order-details-bottom top-order" style="height: 23px;">jhgfre, 483</div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="120">
                          <div class="order-details-top top-order">
                          rtynbv
                          <div>
                            <div class="order-details-bottom top-order">
                          zsdf
                          </div>
                        </td>
                         <td width="120">
                          565897423
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                <div class="color-lateral-finalizada-segundo" id="statu-9">
                </div>
                <div class="tam-tabla-orden">
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: I can´t use top-order in all cells be cause this Class use css so i think i can assign another class like qwerty, can i?

Comment: Yes you can assign another class also

Answer (score 1):

If you want search or sort or ... on table , you can use DataTables jQuery plugins

- Pagination, instant search and multi-column ordering
- Supports almostany data source: Easily theme-able: DataTables, jQuery
  UI, Bootstrap, Foundation
- Ajax auto loading of data
- and ...

  `$('#myTable').DataTable();`

[**DataTables jQuery plugins**](https://www.datatables.net/)

Comment: if i use datatables can i lost my css style apply to my table?

Comment: no , dataTable is theme-able , and you can your customize style for own table ,** [See this](https://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/index.html) **